# Why did I win this game.. About Rules

Tags: rules, poker-theory

This is what took place (online):

Table: 8♥ - Q⋄ - 8♠ - Q♣ - K♠

My hand: 9⋄ - 3⋄

His hand: 4⋄ - J⋄

*Why did it say that I won?*

Answer (score 1):

The board (pot cards) are the best cards here, so you both have the same cards.  That means you both won.  I would assume you only won half the pot.

Comment: @Paparazzi Excuse me? ... It's a pair in the pot, along with K Q Q. The cards held by each player are lower. This answer is right, and by the way, your comment says nothing. "Jack out play"??

Comment: I missed the pair

Comment: @Paparazzi Ahh, aight c: